# Displaying count on bar and percentage on Y-axis of cloumn chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

My series data and column chart look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sajb/tRKad/2/).
series data array values are the count which i need to display on the top of bars and series percentwithingroupvalues array data as in the fiddle should be my Y-axis data.
How to acheive this? Below is my data

```
  series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
                /*Percentage is calculated as
                Below values are random
                (5)*100/(5+2+3)
                */
           percentwithingroupvalues:[20,20,20,20,20]    
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1],
            percentwithingroupvalues:[20,20,20,20,20]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            percentwithingroupvalues:[20,20,20,20,20]
        }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set for each point object `{ }`, instead of value `y` , see: http://jsfiddle.net/tRKad/3/

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {

                    return this.point.custom;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            custom: 5,
            y: 20
        }, {
            custom: 3,
            y: 15
        }, {
            custom: 4,
            y: 11
        }, {
            custom: 22,
            y: 7
        }, {
            custom: 33,
            y: 2
        }],

    }]
```